# Do not escape > within a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have something like this in my bash script:

```
executor="env UNROLL=${u} TB=${tb} ${APP_DIR}/${tp} ${idx} > output.txt" 
$executor
```

which is not working. I realized that the problem is that it is "escaping" the > character, because if I do:

```
executor="env UNROLL=${u} TB=${tb} ${APP_DIR}/${tp} ${idx}" 
$executor > output.txt
```

then it is working properly.

How can I fix it to have everything in a single line?

Comment: Why do you store the command in a string at all? Use `env UNROLL="${u}" TB="${tb}" "${APP_DIR}/${tp}" "${idx}" > output.txt` directly. If you really have to store the command first, do so be defining a function instead of a string.

Comment: Doing that because I am concatenating more things later to "executor" inside a loop. After the loop ends, I execute the resulting "executor" variable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: Do you need to include the redirect in the dynamically constructed part of the command? If not, you can use an array to construct the command safely; if not... it's more complicated to do this right. In any case, read [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing Bash code in variables is a recipe for (un)escaping bugs. Not to mention how dramatically the script’s behavior can change due to (untrusted) values of expanded variables, especially when combined with `eval`.

If you want to store a piece of Bash code for later (re)use, use a function:

```bash
executor() {
  env UNROLL="${u}" TB="${tb}" "${APP_DIR}/${tp}" "${idx}" > output.txt
}

executor
```

A more flexible option would be to get the expanded variables and the target file name from the `executor` function’s arguments, to make it more self-contained and less context-dependent.

```bash
executor() {
  local -n args="$1"
  env UNROLL="${args['UNROLL']}" \
      TB="${args['tb']}" \
  "${args['APP_DIR']}/${args['tp']}" "${args['idx']}" > "${args['output']}"
}

declare -A some_executor_arguments=(
  ['UNROLL']='blah_unroll'
  ['tb']='blah_tb'
  ['APP_DIR']='/some/dir/blah'
  ['tp']='some_app'
  ['idx']='5'
  ['output']='output.txt'
)

executor some_executor_arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I can do that with `eval $executor`

Comment: `eval` will effectively unescape a level more: `a=x; b='printf "%s" "$a"'; c=$($b); declare -p c; d=$(eval $b); declare -p d`

Comment: `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a bug magnet (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)). Short summary: `eval` blurs the line between data and executable code even more than it usually is, leading to all sorts of opportunities for confusion. If you do need to use `eval`, at least double-quote the command string (`eval "$executor"`) to at least limit the confusion.